# Text Scroll Issue in TVOS

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've been trying to make a scrollable text component for tvOS in React Native like the one we see in the terms and conditions box in a lot of applications. The code works fine for android tv but the text doesn't scroll down in tvos.
The code snippet is as follows:

```
<ScrollView 
 style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: getScaledValue(50) }}
 contentContainerStyle= {{ alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}
 removeClippedSubviews={false}
 <Text style={styles.textH2}>
   This is the text portion that needs to be scrolled .............
 </Text>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

try doing wrapping your scrollview with a view with flex:1 and put your scrollview inside it without flex or any other style should do the trick

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
<ScrollView >

< Text style={{alignSelf:"center" }} > This is the text portion that needs to be scrolled .............

< /Text >
 < /ScrollView >
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a quick fix, what I did was that I applied the TVEventHandler on my screen to get events for swipeUp and swipeDown on the siri remote. Then based on these events I changed the y offset of scroll view (increase or decrese) with the checks applied on reached to an end or not. This works fine fine for me.